# Since updating to BlackBerry 10.2, Android app UI gets messed up

Tags: java, android, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I installed the 10.2 update yesterday on my z10 and installed the 10.2 sim but my app's UI is all messed up. It consists of an EditText and TransparentPanel to the right with a Button that lets you show/hide it (runs in landscape). The problem is that now when the app starts the EditText is moved 1/2 way across the screen, the TransparentPanel is to the far left and is only partly visible. I'm assuming it has something to do with the runtime trying to squeeze things into a smaller space now that the ActionBar and bottom bar cannot be hidden.

[image: On launch]

[image: After clicking arrow button]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <com.mobilewebtoolkit.EditTextLineNumbers
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
        android:text="normal"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:visibility="visible" >

    </com.mobilewebtoolkit.EditTextLineNumbers>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webpreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/show_popup_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="950dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tw"
        android:background="@drawable/download_button" />
-

    <com.mobilewebtoolkit.TransparentPanel
        android:id="@+id/tw"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/fileList"
            android:layout_width="239dp"
            android:layout_height="370dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/liveToggle" >
        </ListView>
-

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/commonscroll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
-

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Common"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
-

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="48dp" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/commonTagsBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:text="&lt;>&lt;/>" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/commonTabBtn"
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                        android:text="Tab" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
-

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/htmlscroll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_below="@id/commonscroll" >
-

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="HTML"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
-

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/htmlLinkBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Link" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/htmlImageBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Image" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/htmlUlBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Unordered List" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/htmlOLBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Ordered List" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/htmlTableBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Table" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/htmlFormBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Form" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/htmlInputBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Input" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/htmlTABtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="TextArea" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
-

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/jqueryscroll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/htmlscroll" >
-

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="jQuery"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
-

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/jqMobPage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Page" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/jqMobHeaderBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Header" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/jqMobContentBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Content" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/jqMobFooterBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Footer" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/jqMobNavBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Navbar" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
-

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/cssscroll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/jqueryscroll"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" >
-

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CSS"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
-

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="320dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/cssOpenTagBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                        android:paddingRight="25dp"
                        android:text="{" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/cssCloseTagBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                        android:paddingRight="25dp"
                        android:text="}" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/cssColonTagBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                        android:paddingRight="25dp"
                        android:text=":" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/cssSemiColonBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                        android:paddingRight="25dp"
                        android:text=";" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/cssHyphenBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                        android:paddingRight="25dp"
                        android:text="-" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/prevBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fileList"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cssscroll"
            android:text="@string/preview" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/liveToggle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/prevBtn"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="@string/Liveon"
            android:textOff="@string/Liveoff"
            android:textOn="@string/Liveon" />
    </com.mobilewebtoolkit.TransparentPanel>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

What's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Woops fixed it. Removed android:layout_marginLeft="950dp" from my button